# Align Vertically for all screens

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

```css
.page-section {
    background-color: #035DA9;
    font-family: "Mulish", sans-serif;
}

.logo-image {
    width: 270px;
    margin: 12px 0px 0px 12px;
}

.header-section {
    display: flex;
}

.navbarLinks {
    color: white;
    margin-top: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}

.navbarLinks a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-right: 39px;
    color: white;
}

.middle-section{
   
    width: 100vw;
    margin-left: -8px;
}

.md-sec-1 {
    background-color: #203546;
    display: flex;
}

.middle-section-image {
    width: 270px;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 50px;
}

.text-section {
    color: white;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.text-section p{
    word-spacing: 5px;
}

.md-sec-2{
    color: white;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

.md-sec-2 h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

.footer-section {
    background-color: white;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    display: flex;
}

.btn {
    color: white;
    background: #203546;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    /* margin-left: 47%; */
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

.icons{
    padding: 17px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.icons a{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0px 6px;
}

.color-black {
    color: black;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px){
    .update-contact-section{
        margin-right: 10px !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px){
    .update-image{
        display: inherit !important;
        height: auto;
    }

    .navbarLinks a {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    .navbarLinks {
        margin-top: 12px;
    }

    .logo-update {
        width: 140px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

    .image-responsive {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 57%;
    }

    .header-section-update {
        height: 7vh;
        
    }

    .header-center{
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: -40px;
        /* font-size: 40px; */
    }

    .para-update {
        padding: 0px 10px;
        /* font-size: 30px; */
    }

    

    .fa-icon-update {
        font-size: 10px;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }

    .footer-text-update {
        font-size: 10px; 
        margin-top: 21px;
    }

    .contact-update {
        font-size: 8px; 
        margin-top: 23px;
    }

    .icons {
        padding-left: 0px;
    }

    .text-section {
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px){
    body{
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Intern guys</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./app.css">
    <script src='./font-awesome.js'></script>
</head>

<body class="page-section">
    <div>
        <div class="header-section header-section-update">
            <div class="logo-section">
                <img src="./images/logo_image.png" alt="logo" class="logo-image logo-update" />
            </div>
            <div class="navbarLinks">
                <a href="https://www.internguys.com/">Home</a>
                <a href="https://www.internguys.com/about">About us</a>
                <a href="https://www.internguys.com/signup">Register</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="middle-section">
            <div class="md-sec-1 update-image">
                <div class="image-section">
                    <img src="./images/final-mid-image.png" alt="image" class="middle-section-image image-responsive" />
                </div>
                <div class="text-section">
                    <h3 class="header-center">WELOME TO THE INTERN GUYS</h3>
                    <P class="para-update">Congratulations, you have made the first and last step required to get your internship. Start by
                        creating your profile and you are up and ready for the internship.
                        But don't worry everything is automated, we know exactly where are the pain points are and
                        that’s why we promise to make this as smooth as possible.
                        <i>After all, we are the Inten guys</i>.
                    </P>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="md-sec-2 btn-update">
                <h3 class="quote-update">We are started by the students, built by the students and for the students</h3>
                <a href="" style="text-decoration: none;"><button class="btn">Start now</button></a>
          
        </div>
        <div class="footer-section">
            <div class="icons" style="width: 33vw;">
                <a href=""><i class='fab fa-twitter color-black fa-icon-update'></i></a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/internguys/?hl=en"><i class='fab fa-instagram color-black fa-icon-update'></i></a>                
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/intern-guys/"><i class='fab fa-linkedin color-black fa-icon-update'></i></a>                
                <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@internguys?"><i class='fab fa-tiktok color-black fa-icon-update'></i></a>            
            </div>
            <div style="width: 33vw;">
                <p style="text-align: center; " class="footer-text-update">Built with love in Irvine</p>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 33vw;">
                <p style="float: right; margin-right: 30px;" class="update-contact-section contact-update">Conatct us: xyz@gmail.com</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am making this email template for one of my projects. Here I want that the quote "We are started by students, built by the students ..... " should always appear in the middle(vertically), but I am not able to achieve it. Like if I see my page on a iPad, there is a lot of space between the footer and quote section.
So basically I have to align the content of a div in the middle vertically but for a variable height div. Can anyone  please help me with this

Comment: You need to change the height of the parent divs to 100% and use `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;` on the flexbox div.

Comment: @patrick I did what you asked but still is not working

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    .md-sec-2{
        color: white;
        width:80vw;
        height: 40vh;
        margin:0 auto;
        }

    .quote-update,.btn{
           position: relative;
           top:50%;}
```

Comment: You could assign a variable height to .middle-section (e.g. min-height : 80vh ; ) and then set a margin top in percent to .md-sec-2 (e.g margin-top:40%;) or less or more.